# Passing strings through and array to a struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I'm pretty new to C and I'm not sure what I'm doing. Im trying to create a simple function to create a book. I want to pass two strings in as parameters but I don't know the proper way to access them in C. I have tried many things here is where I am at. Thanks for any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct book {
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
};

struct book createBook(char title[50], char author[50]) {
    struct book x = { title, author };
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to initialize the members this way since they're strings.

Use `strncpy` from `string.h`:

```
#include <string.h>

strncpy(x.title, title, 50);
strncpy(x.author, author, 50);
```

And your declaration would just become:

```
struct book x;
```

Comment: What do you mean?
The variable `x` would be in scope inside `createBook`, subsequent to the declaration `struct book x;`

Comment: Aah, don't mind. I was thinking about another thing and got confused. I was thinking about returning a variable that is declared outside and isn't global.

Answer (score 0):

> Use can't initialize variable or members using this way  struct book
> x = { title, author };
> use strcpy() or strncpy() for initializing member variables
> strncpy_s(x.title, "Kite Book",sizeof(x.title));
> strncpy_s(x.author, "Andre",sizeof(x.author));

or

> strcpy(x.title, "Kite Book");
> strcpy(x.author, "Andre");

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    struct book {
        char title[50];
        char author[50];
    };
    
    struct book createBook(char title[50], char author[50]) {
        struct book x;
    
        strncpy_s(x.title, "Kite Book",sizeof(x.title));
        strncpy_s(x.author, "Andre",sizeof(x.author));
      
        return x;
    }
    int main()
    {
        char title[] = { "Kite" };
        char author[] = { "Andre" };
        createBook(title, author);
    
        return 0;
    
    }
```